How do I restore Keys Cafe app data?
I am using a Samsung Galaxy Z Flip5 and migrating to a new Z Flip5.
I spent a week setting up the Keys Cafe with specific tags on 100s of images that enable me to see pop-up suggestions of memes in my text messages and insert them easily. Now that I am switching to a new phone, I need to know how to migrate those tags (app data) to a new phone.  There does not seem to be any backup option.
